# How to fire form click event even when clicking on user controls in c#

Tags: c#, forms, click, controls, mouse

I need to detect all mouse click from a Windows forms application which has many user controls in it. I can capture every controls click event and pass it to main form but this would not be practicle because form has many custom user controls (over a hundred) and some of the are already using this event. I tried to add click, mouseclick, mouse up and down events but I couldn't make them fire if you click on the user controls instead of an empty part of the form. I searched the net for possible solutions but nothing was satisifactory.

Is there a practicle way to make the form click event fire even clicking on the user controls? I also wellcome any suggestions to record user mouse clicks without using form click event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a click event for a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/180452/how-do-i-set-a-click-event-for-a-form)

Comment: I already checked that thread before posting but I couldn't find a practical solution there. Answer below with handling windows messages seems promising though. I'll reply after I test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    [System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        // 0x210 is WM_PARENTNOTIFY
        // 513 is WM_LBUTTONCLICK
        if (m.Msg == 0x210 && m.WParam.ToInt32() == 513)
        {
            // get the clicked position
            var x = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xFFFF);
            var y = (int)(m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16);

            // get the clicked control
            var childControl = this.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(x, y));

            // call onClick (which fires Click event)
            OnClick(EventArgs.Empty);

            // do something else...
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer codemonkey, it is the most practical solution I have seem on this topic. I was also considering handling windows messages directly but I was not sure how to do that. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old now, but there are solutions that don't involve overriding the WndProc of the form.

For example, you can recursively add a click event to all controls in the control hierarchy using something like this:

```
private void SetupNestedClickEvents(Control control, EventHandler handler)
{
    control.Click += handler;
    foreach (Control ctl in control.Controls)
        SetupNestedClickEvents(ctl, handler);
}
```

You simply call it like this (with `ctl` being the `Form`, `UserControl`, or `Control` you want to apply this to):

```
SetupNestedClickEvents(ctl, (sender, e) => { // Your code here });
```

For example:

```
SetupNestedClickEvents(this, (sender, e) => { Close(); });
```

Run on the current `Form`, will set any control in the hierarchy anywhere under the form to close the form when clicked.