# Event for everything on a form C#

Tags: c#, events, click

I am trying to make a click counter for everything on my form.
My form consists of textboxes, buttons, pictureboxes and labels.
What my problem is that my picutrebox is covering the whole form because I want it as a background picture. So when I have the `private void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` event on it doesn't register the clicks that are on the picture box. And when I have `private void pictureBox2_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)` event the code it doesn't register any of the clicks I do on the buttons or text boxes. Is there an event for a click on absolutely everything on the form?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a click event for a form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180452/how-do-i-set-a-click-event-for-a-form)

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways you can handle this.

One way is to send the picture box back so your buttons come on top like this:

```
pictureBox.SendToBack();
```

Or you can attach an event handler to all of your controls like this:

```
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    control.Click += Control_Click;
}
```